# How to prefill a form with Cloud Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of accounts that I have stored in Firestore, and when I want to edit the accounts, I want to be able to have the current information already pre-filled with what is there. I'm able to grab the correct info, and can print to console that the information is there, but the fields will not pre-fill with the information. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is part of the code for my editscreen form:

````
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './nav_bar.dart';

class EditSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditSettings({
    super.key,
  });
  static const routeName = '/edit-settings';

  @override
  State<EditSettings> createState() => _EditSettingsState();
}

class _EditSettingsState extends State<EditSettings> {
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void homeRoute(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushReplacementNamed(NavBar.routeName);
  }

  final _urlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _usernameFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();
  //final _confirmPassFocusNode = FocusNode();


  var _initValues = {
    'siteName': '',
    'siteUrl': '',
    'userName': '',
    'password': '',
  };

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _urlFocusNode.dispose();
    _usernameFocusNode.dispose();
    _passwordFocusNode.dispose();
    //_confirmPassFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  var _isInit = true;

  bool _passwordVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _passwordVisible = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    if (_isInit) {
      if (ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments != null) {
        final accountId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
        if (accountId.isNotEmpty) {
          final _editedAccount = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('accounts').doc(accountId).get();
          print(Text(_editedAccount.data().toString()));
          _initValues = {
            'siteName': _editedAccount['siteName'],
            'siteUrl': _editedAccount['url'],
            'userName': _editedAccount['username'],
            'password': _editedAccount['password'],
          };
        }
      }
      _isInit = false;
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Edit Settings')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 40,
          left: 10,
          right: 10,
        ),
        child: Form(
          key: _form,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['siteName'],    <---- This part does not work
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Name of Site',
                  hintText: 'Site Name',
                ),```


I have changed the async method, attempted to grab the instance outside of didChangeDependencies but I may have implemented that incorrectly. Any assistance would be appreciated!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out! I had to use a future builder, return the data and pass in the return value. Here's the code for anyone looking for something similar!

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './nav_bar.dart';

class EditSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditSettings({
    super.key,
  });
  static const routeName = '/edit-settings';

  @override
  State<EditSettings> createState() => _EditSettingsState();
}

class _EditSettingsState extends State<EditSettings> {
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void homeRoute(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushReplacementNamed(NavBar.routeName);
  }

  final _urlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _usernameFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();
  //final _confirmPassFocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _urlFocusNode.dispose();
    _usernameFocusNode.dispose();
    _passwordFocusNode.dispose();
    //_confirmPassFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool _passwordVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _passwordVisible = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async {
    final accountId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;

    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('accounts')
        .doc(accountId)
        .get();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Edit Settings')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 40,
          left: 10,
          right: 10,
        ),
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, querySnapshot) {
            if (querySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return Form(
              key: _form,
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    initialValue: querySnapshot.data!['siteName'],
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Name of Site',
                      hintText: 'Site Name',
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setState after getting the initial value to update the UI state.

```
    @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    if (_isInit) {
      if (ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments != null) {
        final accountId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
        if (accountId.isNotEmpty) {
          final _editedAccount = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('accounts').doc(accountId).get();
          print(Text(_editedAccount.data().toString()));
       ///add setSetate here
       setState({
        initValues = {
            'siteName': _editedAccount['siteName'],
            'siteUrl': _editedAccount['url'],
            'userName': _editedAccount['username'],
            'password': _editedAccount['password'],
          };
        })
          _
        }
      }
      _isInit = false;
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding setState doesnt fix it. I'll click on the account to bring the edit screen and nothing is prefilled even after that.

Comment: So after doing some testing, I found that it is building the UI before it actually grabs the values. Is there a way to make it wait for the values to be grabbed? I found a future builder but honestly dont know how to make that work with what I am doing

Comment: The setState will rebuild the UI. But in your case instead of grabbing the values inside didChangeDependencies you should grab values inside init method.